# Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/ContentCut'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

On one of my React project, I'm using Material-UI icons with those info in my package.json

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.9.10",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
```

All icons are working fine until I added the icon `ContentCut` which is availabe at [this link](https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=content_cut&style=baseline):
[image]

this is how I'm importing it:

```
import ContentCutIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ContentCut';
```

but I get the error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/ContentCut'

I tried by upgrading the icons package using yarn:

```
yarn upgrade @material-ui/core --latest
yarn upgrade @material-ui/icons --latest
```

but it does not solve the problem.

I created this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-grass-13gem?file=/src/App.js) with the fixed latest version of `@material-ui/icons` which is today v1.4.9 as described on the [npm project page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/icons) to illustrate the problem (comment the `ContentCut` import line to see the error).

Does anyone solved this specific issue (when the icon is available but the import is not possible even after an npm/yarn upgrade)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the search here to see which icons are part of `@material-ui/icons`: https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/. ContentCut is not there.

If you have the svg for an icon such as from the material.io site, you can create an `SvgIcon` element by grabbing the `path` element from the svg:

```
const ContentCutIcon = createSvgIcon(
  <path d="M9.64 7.64c.23-.5.36-1.05.36-1.64 0-2.21-1.79-4-4-4S2 3.79 2 6s1.79 4 4 4c.59 0 1.14-.13 1.64-.36L10 12l-2.36 2.36C7.14 14.13 6.59 14 6 14c-2.21 0-4 1.79-4 4s1.79 4 4 4 4-1.79 4-4c0-.59-.13-1.14-.36-1.64L12 14l7 7h3v-1L9.64 7.64zM6 8c-1.1 0-2-.89-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .89 2 2-.9 2-2 2zm0 12c-1.1 0-2-.89-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .89 2 2-.9 2-2 2zm6-7.5c-.28 0-.5-.22-.5-.5s.22-.5.5-.5.5.22.5.5-.22.5-.5.5zM19 3l-6 6 2 2 7-7V3z" />,
  "ContentCut"
);
```

Here is a working version of your sandbox leveraging this:

```
import React from "react";
import MailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mail";
import ForwardIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Forward";
import createSvgIcon from "@material-ui/icons/utils/createSvgIcon";

const ContentCutIcon = createSvgIcon(
  <path d="M9.64 7.64c.23-.5.36-1.05.36-1.64 0-2.21-1.79-4-4-4S2 3.79 2 6s1.79 4 4 4c.59 0 1.14-.13 1.64-.36L10 12l-2.36 2.36C7.14 14.13 6.59 14 6 14c-2.21 0-4 1.79-4 4s1.79 4 4 4 4-1.79 4-4c0-.59-.13-1.14-.36-1.64L12 14l7 7h3v-1L9.64 7.64zM6 8c-1.1 0-2-.89-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .89 2 2-.9 2-2 2zm0 12c-1.1 0-2-.89-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .89 2 2-.9 2-2 2zm6-7.5c-.28 0-.5-.22-.5-.5s.22-.5.5-.5.5.22.5.5-.22.5-.5.5zM19 3l-6 6 2 2 7-7V3z" />,
  "ContentCut"
);
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>This is three working icons</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <MailIcon />
        </li>
        <li>
          <ForwardIcon />
        </li>
        <li>
          <ContentCutIcon />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit ContentCut icon]

Comment: Thanks, it works. I did the same thing for other icons. I can found the SVG codes from this URL https://iconify.design/icon-sets/mdi/content-paste.html (for ContentPasteIcon for example).

Answer (score 2):

Install the material core library:

```
npm install @material-ui/core
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution that works for me:

```
    npm i @material-ui/icons
```

Answer (score 1):

`npm install @mui/icons-material` is the cure for this problems

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing with react run this in the terminal 
`yarn add @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It means the ContentCut is not available in the node_modules.

One way to solve this is to create files manually and save to icons folder inside node_modules. I already create file for your ContentCut SVG code.

**ContentCut.js**

```
"use strict";

var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = void 0;

var _react = _interopRequireDefault(require("react"));

var _createSvgIcon = _interopRequireDefault(require("./utils/createSvgIcon"));

var _default = (0, _createSvgIcon.default)(_react.default.createElement("path", {
  d: "M9.64 7.64c.23-.5.36-1.05.36-1.64 0-2.21-1.79-4-4-4S2 3.79 2 6s1.79 4 4 4c.59 0 1.14-.13 1.64-.36L10 12l-2.36 2.36C7.14 14.13 6.59 14 6 14c-2.21 0-4 1.79-4 4s1.79 4 4 4 4-1.79 4-4c0-.59-.13-1.14-.36-1.64L12 14l7 7h3v-1L9.64 7.64zM6 8c-1.1 0-2-.89-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .89 2 2-.9 2-2 2zm0 12c-1.1 0-2-.89-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .89 2 2-.9 2-2 2zm6-7.5c-.28 0-.5-.22-.5-.5s.22-.5.5-.5.5.22.5.5-.22.5-.5.5zM19 3l-6 6 2 2 7-7V3z"
}), 'ContentCut');

exports.default = _default;
```

**ContentCut.d.ts**

```
export { default } from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon';
```

**add to this path**
\node_modules@material-ui\icons

then this import to your component

```
import ContentCutIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ContentCut';

<ContentCutIcon />
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue in react functionnal component, seems link to instance. I have this working but if audio is inside SongButton, it doesn't work anymore

```
const audio = new Audio("../song.mp3")
const SongButton = () =>{

const [isAudio, setIsAudio] = React.useState(false)

const onClick = () => {
    if(isAudio){
        audio.pause();
        //audio.currentTime = 0;
    }else{
        audio.play();
    }
    setIsAudio(!isAudio);
  }

  if(isAudio){
      return (
          <div className="SongButtonDiv">
               <PauseCircleOutlineIcon onClick={onClick} fontSize="large" />
          </div>
      )
  }else{
      return (
          <div className="SongButtonDiv">
               <PlayCircleOutlineIcon onClick={onClick} fontSize="large"/>
          </div>
       )
   }
}
export default SongButton
```

Comment: What is PauseCircleOutlineIcon? I don't see that declared anywhere and the question is regarding how to resolve an import error.