# How to use Material-UI CDN in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

Pretty new to react development, I wanted to use include some clean icons in my app so I decided on using material-UI icons however I want to use the CDN instead of install the library in the app.

I copied this CDN link from the site and place it in **public/ index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
```

**Problem :** Tried using Material-UI CDN in my react app but getting an error.

```
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/ArrowDropDownRounded'
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Can you show us how you implement the Icon, with code for reference? From what you attached, it isn't hinting anything other than you didn't install the @material-ui/icons package.

Comment: Check the Solution that have been already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62543530/module-not-found-cant-resolve-material-ui-icons-contentcut)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to use Material Design icon is to use the `<Icon></Icon>` from `@material-ui/core`. Please refer to the official `@material-ui/core` documentation by clicking on this [link](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#icon-font-icons).

To implement icon, please refer the code below.

```
import { Icon } from @material-ui/core

...
<Icon> [YOUR_DESIRED_ICON] </Icon>
...
```

Please replace [YOUR_DESIRED_ICON] with icons that are available in the CDN referring to this [link](https://fonts.google.com/icons).

Hope this resolved your issue. Have a nice day. If you don't understand, please refer to this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-villani-cn5k2?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

To Install Material-ui packages

```
npm install @material-ui/core 
npm install @material-ui/icons
```

Code

```
import React from "react";
import MailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mail";
import ForwardIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Forward";
import createSvgIcon from "@material-ui/icons/utils/createSvgIcon";

const ContentCutIcon = createSvgIcon(
  <path d="M9.64 7.64c.23-.5.36-1.05.36-1.64 0-2.21-1.79-4-4-4S2 3.79 2 6s1.79 4 4 4c.59 0 1.14-.13 1.64-.36L10 12l-2.36 2.36C7.14 14.13 6.59 14 6 14c-2.21 0-4 1.79-4 4s1.79 4 4 4 4-1.79 4-4c0-.59-.13-1.14-.36-1.64L12 14l7 7h3v-1L9.64 7.64zM6 8c-1.1 0-2-.89-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .89 2 2-.9 2-2 2zm0 12c-1.1 0-2-.89-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .89 2 2-.9 2-2 2zm6-7.5c-.28 0-.5-.22-.5-.5s.22-.5.5-.5.5.22.5.5-.22.5-.5.5zM19 3l-6 6 2 2 7-7V3z" />,
  "ContentCut"
);
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>This is three working icons</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <MailIcon />
        </li>
        <li>
          <ForwardIcon />
        </li>
        <li>
          <ContentCutIcon />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check the Code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/contentcut-icon-92dbh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: the actual question was about using the material ui icons from CDN and not from npm package